# The number of online users based on start and end time of a duration

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a login log data of each login's login & logout time, the data is like:

```
   uid     login      logout
   123     10:15:00   10:18:00
   666     10:17:00   10:20:00
   123     10:20:00   10:33:00
   ...
```

The output is to calculate the number of online at that time users every 1 minute, e.g.:

```
time_point  cnt_uid
10:15:00       1
10:16:00       1
10:17:00       2
10:18:00       2
10:19:00       1
10:20:00       2
...
```

Sorry I didn't put my attempt, really no idea about it...

You don't need to put the whole sql, some key words are fine. Thanks for your help in advance..

I am using MySQL 5.7

Comment: I would suggest that you update to MySQL 8+.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the datetime you want to check at is 'T'.

So a user will be considered online at T, if login time is less than or equal to 'T' and logout time is greater than  'T'.

So a condition can be like

where login <= T and logout > T

And since you are looking for a 1 min interval, you probably want to wrap it in a function which takes start and end time as argument.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I can understand now. The only question is how to generate the time column. What is  the function you mentioned at the end? Is it ready in MySQL 8.0 or is it a self defined function?

Answer (score 0):

First find a way to get a table containing time_point, join, and then aggregate. So, which step are you unclear about?

Comment: For instance, how to generate a column which comprises every minute during a time interval?

Comment: Prepare a table `table1` that is large enough,and execute the following query.`create table num as
select @num:= @num+1 num from table1 t1, (select @num:= 0) t2
;`,`select date_add('2021/08/16 10:15:00', interval num minute) from num where num <= 5;`